# Does the System.Diagnostics.Process.Exited Event Always Fire?

Tags: c#, process, c#-2.0

I have an application that I am writting that communicates with a third-party program through a COM connection.  I was tasked to strengthen the resilency of our application, in order to do that I wait until the third-party application is ready.  I do this by waiting until the return value on a method that returns true only when the third-party application has been fully loaded.

In an effort to avoid the condition where the application crashes during this procedure, and my application just sits there waiting throwing COM errors( caught of course ) I was wondering if the Exited event on the Process itself, is guaranteed to always happen?

I am more then willing to provide additional details when its possible.  ***I am also for the time being limited to .NET Framework 2.0 with this current build.***

Comment: Are you talking about the waitforexit() method of the process?

Comment: @DanielCasserly - No...I am talking about the Exited event that you can subscribe to, if you want to be notified when Windows starts the exit procedure on a process, the method are talking about wouldn't be any use to me.  I am only worried about the crashes I cannot simulate, I want to be able to cover most of those cases, I had hoped I was mistaken about how the Exited event and exit procedure on a process worked.

Comment: Why must I suffer because of a serial downvoter?

Comment: I didn't downvote you if you are referring to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the sort of crash - some crashes leave the "process" in memory (for example just stuck in some never-ending loop OR that COM object opened some modal error dialog and waits for user)... these cases are not covered by any method mentioned in your description...

In my experience to be really resilient you need a combination:

- hook the Exited event (if you started the application via Process) OR find the process ID and monitor that
- catch any exceptions from that COM object
- implement a timeout + abort logic for calls to that COM object/application
- "monitor" the COM object/app
  I usually start a separate thread before calling such a COM object... that thread monitors the COM object/application for example if it open any window it is not supposed or memory consumption goes through the roof when it is not supposed to etc. - the things monitored and the reaction to each of them is rather specific to that COM object/application...

Comment: I was afraid of the "it depends" answer.  I am limited in what I can do, the good news is I have most of those, the seperate thread because of the current design might be more trouble then its worth.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand... but that is the nature of the term "crash" - it can mean anything... I had even a COM process crashing right into BSOD, not much to be done about that (except monitoring the machine of course (from a second one that is)...

Comment: I understand the term "crash" could mean anything. I was just was looking for the Windows will run through the exit procedure ( i hate to use this word ) 'always'